# Textselecter not working in listview

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview in listview item . When i tried the selecter with other textviews it is working fine. I tried android:state_activated="true" also.But it is not working.this is my textview color selecter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/ps_blue"/>

<!-- <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/ps_blue"/> -->


<!-- <item android:state_enabled="true" android:color="@color/ps_blue"/> -->


<!-- <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/ps_blue"/> -->


<!--
<item android:state_active="true" android:color="@color/ps_blue"/>
<item android:state_window_focused="true" android:color="@color/ps_blue"/>
-->

<item android:state_activated="true" android:color="@color/ps_blue"/>
<item android:color="@color/text_grey"/>
<!-- default -->
```

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/menulayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/menu_selector"
android:orientation="vertical" 
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewsliding"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:textColor="@color/menutxtview"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show your list_items xml file.